# How to determine column to be Quantitative or Categorical data?

Tags: r, machine-learning

If I have a file with many column, the data are all numbers, how can I know whether a specific column is categorical or quantitative data?. Is there an area of study for this kind of problem? If not, what are some heuristics that can be used to determine?

Some heuristics that I can think of:

#### Likely to be categorical data

- make a summary of the unique value, if it's < `some_threshold`, there is higher chance to be categorical data.
- if the data is highly concentrate (low std.)
- if the unique value are highly sequential, and starts from 1
- if all the value in column has fixed length (may be ID/Date)
- if it has a very small p-value at [Benford's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)
- if it has a very small p-value at the Chi-square test against the result column

#### Likely to be quantitative data

- if the column has floating number
- if the column has sparse value
- if the column has negative value

#### Other

- Maybe quantitative data are more likely to be near/next to quantitative data (vice-versa)

I am using R, but the question doesn't need to be R specific.

Comment: Use `unique` to all the columns. If there are only few "levels" it might be a categorical variable. To do it at once, use
`apply(cars,2,unique)`

Comment: Yes, this is my first item. My problem is: how do you define "few", should it be based on relative number of the dataset(such as 0.1% of n), or should it be like an absolute number (< 3,000)

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the data...

Comment: I don't think you can ever *know* with certainty based just on the data.  To know you need *understanding*.  One source of understanding is metadata: data about data.  For example, a schema; a data reporting (or recording) plan; a study protocol.

Answer (score 2):

This assumes someone coded the data correctly.

Perhaps you are suggesting the data were not coded or labeled correctly, that it was all entered as numeric and some of it really is categorical.  In that case, I do not know how one could tell with any certainty.  Categorical data can have decimals places and can be negative.

The question I would ask myself in such a situation is what difference does it make how I treat the data?

If you are interested in the second scenario perhaps you should ask your question on Stack Exchange.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
    aa     bb      cc     dd
    10    100    1000      1
    20    200    2000      2
    30    300    3000      3
    40    400    4000      4
    50    500    5000      5
    60    600    6000      6
', header = TRUE, colClasses = c('numeric', 'character', 'numeric', 'character'))

my.data

# one way
str(my.data)

'data.frame':   6 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ aa: num  10 20 30 40 50 60
 $ bb: chr  "100" "200" "300" "400" ...
 $ cc: num  1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000
 $ dd: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Here is a way to record the information:

```
my.class <- rep('empty', ncol(my.data))

for(i in 1:ncol(my.data)) {
    my.class[i] <- class(my.data[,i])
}

> my.class
[1] "numeric"   "character" "numeric"   "character"
```

**EDIT**

Here is a way to record `class` for each column without using a `for-loop`:

```
my.class <- sapply(my.data, class)
```

Comment: Yes, assuming that the data is been coded correctly; and yes it's possible that one can code categorical data with float/negative value, still, if the categorical data have been converted to number, is there some pattern to be discovered?

Comment: I do not know of one that can be used with certainty and suggest you ask at Stack Exchange.  That is a statistics site.

Comment: you mean `stats` exchange ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first cut at an R function using most of those suggestions:

```r
require( "hablar" )
require( "DescTools" )

# unique.p - threshold for unique values as a proportion of total cases
# unique.n - if unique values of x < unique.n then classify as factor
# first.n - if 90% of cases are contained within the first.n levels then classify as a factor 
# max.v - if x is an integer and the variance of x is below max.v then classify as a factor
# b.to.f - convert binary variables (x in 0,1) to factors? 



is_factor <- function( x, unique.p=0.10, unique.n=(length(x)*unique.p),  
                       first.n=25, max.v=2, b.to.f=FALSE )
{
  cat( paste0( "\n-----------------  ", deparse(substitute(x)), "\n\n" ) )

  # exclude NA, NaN, and Inf

  if( is.numeric(x) | is.logical(x) )
  {  x <- x[ is.finite(x) ] }

  if( is.character(x) )
  {  
    x[ x == "NaN" | x == "Inf" ] <- NA
    x <- na.omit(x)
  }
 

  n <- length(x)

  if( n == 0 )
  {
    cat( "The variable is empty (all NAs)" )
    return(FALSE)
  }

  cat( paste0( "Valid N (after NA drop) = ", n, "\n" ) )
  cat( paste0( "Unique levels/values of x = ", length(unique(x)), "\n" ) )
  cat( paste0( "unique.n argument = ", unique.n, "\n" ) )
  cat( paste0( "unique.p argument = ", unique.p, "\n\n" ) )

  if( "factor" %in% class(x) )
  { 
    cat( "has class FACTOR \n" )
    cat( paste0( "Values of x: \n", paste( head( unique(x), 10 ), collapse=",\n" ), "\n\n" ) )
    cat( "####   IS FACTOR   #### \n\n\n" )
    return(TRUE) 
  }

  if( "logical" %in% class(x) )
  { 
    cat( "has class LOGICAL: is NOT a factor \n\n" )
    cat( paste0( "Values of x: \n", paste( head( unique(x), 10 ), collapse=",\n" ), "\n\n" ) )
    return(FALSE) 
  }

  if( any( DescTools::IsDate(x) ) )
  {
    x.dates <- x[ DescTools::IsDate(x) ]
    cat( "x has class DATE: is NOT a factor \n" )
    cat( paste0( "Values of x: \n", paste( head( unique(x.dates), 10 ), collapse=",\n" ) ) )
    return(FALSE)
  }
  
  if( "character" %in% class(x) )
  {
    cat( "x has class CHARACTER: \n\n" )

    # is a logical vector
    if( length(unique(x)) == 1 )
    { 
      cat( "All values of x are the same: \n" )
      cat( paste0( "Values of x: \n", paste( head( unique(x), 10 ), collapse=",\n" ), "\n" ) )
      if( b.to.f )
      { 
        cat( "Convert binary to factor is set to TRUE \n\n" )
        cat( "####   IS FACTOR   #### \n\n\n" )
        return(TRUE) 
      }
      cat( "Convert binary to factor is set to FALSE \n\n" )
      return(FALSE) 
    }


    # strings with same length (standardized categories) 
    #  but keep the total levels low so it doesn't flag IDs
    is.same <- length( unique( nchar(x) ) ) == 1  & length(unique(x)) < ( n * unique.p )
    
    if( is.same )
    { 
      cat( "All strings have the same number of characters \n\n" )
      cat( paste0( "Values of x (first 10): \n", paste( head( unique(x), 10 ), collapse=",\n" ), "\n\n" ) ) 
    }
    
    # small number of unique cases
    n.unique <- length( unique( x ) ) 
    
    # small prop of total cases unique
    p.unique <- length( unique( x ) ) / n
    
    is.small.unique.n <- n.unique <= unique.n & p.unique <= unique.p

    if( is.small.unique.n )
    { 
      cat( "x has a small number & proportion of unique cases\n" )
      cat( paste0( "N < ", unique.n, " & prop < ", unique.p, "\n" ) )
      cat( paste0( "Number of unique values of x: ", length(unique(x)), "\n" ) )
      cat( paste0( "Values of x (first 10): \n", paste( head( sort(unique(x)), 10 ), collapse=",\n" ), "\n\n" ) )
    }
   
    # most common levels account for large portion of total
    
    first.n.total <- table(x) %>% sort(desc=T) %>% head( first.n ) %>% sum() 
    total.p <- first.n.total / n
    is.large.p.total <- total.p > 0.90

    first.n.levels <- table(x) %>% sort(desc=T) %>% head( first.n ) %>% names()

    if( is.large.p.total )
    { 
      cat( paste0( "First ", first.n, " levels accounts for > 90% of total cases \n" ) ) 
      cat( paste0( "First N levels: \n", paste( first.n.levels, collapse=",\n" ), "\n\n" ) )
    }
    
    # if it meets any criteria return factor
    if( is.same | is.small.unique.n | is.large.p.total )
    { 
      cat( "####   IS FACTOR   #### \n\n\n" )
      return(TRUE) 
    }
  }
  
  # only test integers 
  x <- hablar::retype(x)

  if( "numeric" %in% class(x) )
  { 
    cat( "x is non-integer number: NOT a factor \n\n" )
    cat( paste0( "Values of x (first 10): \n", paste( head( unique(x), 10 ), collapse=",\n" ), "\n\n" ) )
    return(FALSE)
  }
  
  if( "integer" %in% class(x) )
  {
    cat( "x has class INTEGER: \n\n" )

    # is a logical vector
    if( all( x %in% c(0,1) ) | length(unique(x))==1 )
    { 
      cat( "All values of x are 0/1 or a single value: \n" )
      cat( paste0( "Values of x: \n", paste( head( unique(x), 10 ), collapse=",\n" ), "\n" ) )
      if( b.to.f )
      { 
        cat( "Convert binary to factor is set to TRUE \n\n" )
        cat( "####   IS FACTOR   #### \n\n\n" )
        return(TRUE) 
      }
      cat( "Convert binary to factor is set to FALSE \n\n" )
      return(FALSE) 
    }
    
    # has negative values 
    if( any( x < 0 ) )
    { 
      cat( "Contains negative integers \n" )
      cat( paste0( "Range x: ", range(x), "\n\n" ) )
      return(FALSE) 
    }
    
    # small numer of unique values
    n.unique <- length( unique( x ) ) 
    
    # small prop of total cases unique
    p.unique <- length( unique( x ) ) / n
    
    is.small.unique.n <- n.unique <= unique.n & p.unique <= unique.p

    if( is.small.unique.n )
    { 
      cat( "x has a small number & proportion of unique cases \n" )
      cat( paste0( "unique(x) < ", unique.n, " & unique(x)/length(x) < ", unique.p, " \n" ) )
      cat( paste0( "Number of unique values of x: ", length(unique(x)), "\n" ) )
      cat( paste0( "Values of x (first 10): \n", paste( head( sort(unique(x)), 10 ), collapse=",\n" ), "\n\n" ) )
    }
    
    # starts with 1 and is an approximate sequence
    starts.with.one <- min(x) == 1 
    width.of.range.x <- max(x) - min(x) + 1
    is.approx.seq <- length(unique(x)) / width.of.range.x > 0.8
    
    is.seq.from.one <- starts.with.one & is.approx.seq

    if( is.seq.from.one )
    { cat( "x is an approximate sequence of integers starting with one \n\n" ) }
    
    # is a true sequence, e.g. 9,10,11,12
    is.true.seq <- length(unique(x)) == width.of.range.x & 
                   length(unique(x))/length(x) < unique.p

    if( is.true.seq )
    { 
      cat( "x is a true sequence of integers \n" )
      cat( paste0( "Values: \n", paste( sort(unique(x)), collapse=",\n" ), "\n\n" ) )
    }
    
    # equal intervals between all numbers
    is.equal.intervals <- length( unique( x[-1] - x[-length(x)] ) ) == 1
    
    if( is.equal.intervals )
    {
      cat( "All values of x have equal intervals between them \n" )
      cat( paste0( "Values: ", paste( head(sort(unique(x))), collapse="," ), "\n\n" ) )
    }

    # small variance
    is.small.var <- var(x) < max.v

    if( is.small.var )
    { cat( paste0( "The variance of x is below ", max.v, "\n\n" ) ) }
    
    # if it meets any criteria return factor
    if( is.small.unique.n | is.seq.from.one | is.true.seq | is.equal.intervals )
    { 
      cat( "####   IS FACTOR   #### \n\n\n" )
      return(TRUE) 
    }  
  }

  cat( "There are a large number of unique values: x is NOT a factor \n" )
  cat( paste0( "Number of unique values of x: ", length(unique(x)), "\n" ) )
  cat( paste0( "Values of x (first 10): \n", paste( head( sort(unique(x)), 10 ), collapse=",\n" ), "\n\n" ) )
  return( FALSE )
}
```

Sample dataset: mtcars:

Potential factors could be:

- cyl (number of cylinders)
- gear (number of gears)
- carb (number of carburetors)
- vs (v-shaped or straight engine in 0/1)
- am (auto or manual transmission in 0/1)

Cyl and gear get flagged as factors. Carb has 6 unique values or 6/32 = 18% unique proportion score, above the 10% threshold set by unique.p.

Those arguments will be sensitive to the sample size - for example, 50 unique state codes represent a large proportion of total values in a dataset with a couple hundred addresses but the number of states won't grow with size so the proportion of unique values over total cases naturally gets smaller as the dataset grows. These demo datasets are sensitive.

The argument "b.to.f" can be set to TRUE if you want binary variables to be flagged as factors: vs and am in this example.

```r
#   mpg Miles/(US) gallon
#   cyl Number of cylinders
#   disp    Displacement (cu.in.)
#   hp  Gross horsepower
#   drat    Rear axle ratio
#   wt  Weight (1000 lbs)
#   qsec    1/4 mile time
#   vs  Engine (0 = V-shaped, 1 = straight)
#   am  Transmission (0 = automatic, 1 = manual)
#   gear    Number of forward gears
#   carb    Number of carburetors

> head( mtcars )
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

```
lapply( mtcars, is_factor )

-----------------  mpg

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 25
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x is non-integer number: NOT a factor 

Values of x (first 10): 
21,
22.8,
21.4,
18.7,
18.1,
14.3,
24.4,
19.2,
17.8,
16.4


-----------------  cyl

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 3
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x has class INTEGER: 

x has a small number & proportion of unique cases 
unique(x) < 3.2 & unique(x)/length(x) < 0.1 
Number of unique values of x: 3
Values of x (first 10): 
4,
6,
8

####   IS FACTOR   #### 



-----------------  disp

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 27
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x is non-integer number: NOT a factor 

Values of x (first 10): 
160,
108,
258,
360,
225,
146.7,
140.8,
167.6,
275.8,
472


-----------------  hp

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 22
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x has class INTEGER: 

There are a large number of unique values: x is NOT a factor 
Number of unique values of x: 22
Values of x (first 10): 
52,
62,
65,
66,
91,
93,
95,
97,
105,
109


-----------------  drat

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 22
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x is non-integer number: NOT a factor 

Values of x (first 10): 
3.9,
3.85,
3.08,
3.15,
2.76,
3.21,
3.69,
3.92,
3.07,
2.93
 

-----------------  wt

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 29
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x is non-integer number: NOT a factor 

Values of x (first 10): 
2.62,
2.875,
2.32,
3.215,
3.44,
3.46,
3.57,
3.19,
3.15,
4.07


-----------------  qsec

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 30
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x is non-integer number: NOT a factor 

Values of x (first 10): 
16.46,
17.02,
18.61,
19.44,
20.22,
15.84,
20,
22.9,
18.3,
18.9


-----------------  vs

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 2
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x has class INTEGER: 

All values of x are 0/1 or a single value: 
Values of x: 
0,
1
Convert binary to factor is set to FALSE 


-----------------  am

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 2
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x has class INTEGER: 

All values of x are 0/1 or a single value: 
Values of x: 
1,
0
Convert binary to factor is set to FALSE 


-----------------  gear

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 3
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x has class INTEGER: 

x has a small number & proportion of unique cases 
unique(x) < 3.2 & unique(x)/length(x) < 0.1 
Number of unique values of x: 3
Values of x (first 10): 
3,
4,
5

x is a true sequence of integers 
Values: 
3,
4,
5

The variance of x is below 2

####   IS FACTOR   #### 



-----------------  carb

Valid N (after NA drop) = 32
Unique levels/values of x = 6
unique.n argument = 3.2
unique.p argument = 0.1

x has class INTEGER: 

There are a large number of unique values: x is NOT a factor 
Number of unique values of x: 6
Values of x (first 10): 
1,
2,
3,
4,
6,
8


$mpg
[1] FALSE

$cyl
[1] TRUE

$disp
[1] FALSE

$hp
[1] FALSE

$drat
[1] FALSE

$wt
[1] FALSE

$qsec
[1] FALSE

$vs
[1] FALSE

$am
[1] FALSE

$gear
[1] TRUE

$carb
[1] FALSE
```