# How does lm() know which predictors are categorical?

Tags: r, regression

Normally, me and you(assuming you're not a bot) are easily able to identify whether a predictor is *categorical* or *quantitative*. Like, for example, gender is obviously categorical. Your last vote can be classified categorically.
Basically, we can identify categorical predictors easily. But what happens when we input some data in `R`, and it's `lm` function makes dummy variables for a predictor? How does it do that?

Somewhat [related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809192/how-to-determine-column-to-be-quantitative-or-categorical-data) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search R `factor` function. Here is a small demo, first model uses number of cylinder as a numerical valuable. Second model uses it as a categorical variable.

```
> summary(lm(mpg~cyl,mtcars))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9814 -2.1185  0.2217  1.0717  7.5186 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  37.8846     2.0738   18.27  < 2e-16 ***
cyl          -2.8758     0.3224   -8.92 6.11e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.206 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7262,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7171 
F-statistic: 79.56 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 6.113e-10

> summary(lm(mpg~factor(cyl),mtcars))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.2636 -1.8357  0.0286  1.3893  7.2364 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   26.6636     0.9718  27.437  < 2e-16 ***
factor(cyl)6  -6.9208     1.5583  -4.441 0.000119 ***
factor(cyl)8 -11.5636     1.2986  -8.905 8.57e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.223 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7325,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.714 
F-statistic:  39.7 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 4.979e-09
```

Comment: No, actually I am talking about the automatic dummy variable generation by `lm` for certain predictors, without any explicit specification. Example: In the ISLR package, there is a `Carseats` data set, on which if we run `summary(lm(Sales~.+Income:Advertising+Price:Age,data=Carseats))`, then we'll automatically get dummy variables for the predictor `ShelveLoc`.

Comment: @Mooncrater Check `class(Carseats$ShelveLoc)`. Compare `class(Carseats$Sales)`.

Comment: If the column is character or factor, `lm` will treat it as categorical and create dummy codings. If the column is numeric or integer, `lm` will treat it as numeric. You can check this with, for example, `Carseats$ShelveLoc = as.character(Carseats$ShelveLoc)`, `Carseats$Age = as.character(Carseats$Age)` etc. and then seeing how these variables are treated in an `lm` model compared to their original coding.

Comment: Or, if you want to see the actual data encoding that goes into the model, do `model.matrix(Sales ~ Age + ShelveLoc, data=Carseats)` and see how it changes when you change the class of `Age` or `ShelveLoc`. `lm` calls `model.matrix` to generate the matrix of predictor variables used to fit the model.

Comment: Thanks @Kodiologist @eipi10 @hxd1011 @HarshitMehta and @Pere! It's almost clear now. But, consider the data `Auto` for example. If I do `Auto = read.table("Auto.data",header=TRUE,na.strings="?")`, then `class(Auto$horsepower)` gives `numeric`, whereas `Auto2=read.table("Auto.data",header=TRUE)` then `class(Auto2$horsepower)` gives `factor`. Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you add some `"?"` values to `horsepower` before you saved `Auto.data` as a file, because all the values are integers in the native data frame? I can only reproduce that behavior if I add a string value to at least one row of `Auto$horsepower` before saving it.

Comment: You're seeing this behavior because in the first case, all `"?"` values in `horsepower` are converted to `NA` and the remaining values are numeric, so the resulting column is parsed as numeric. In the second case, there's at least one  non-numeric value in `horsepower` so R treats that column as a column of character strings. But the (annoying) default behavior of `read.table` is convert strings to factor class. If you add the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to `read.table` the second case will result in `horsepower` being `character` class instead of `factor`.

Comment: How `read.table` determines which columns are factor, character, or numeric is a separate issue from how `lm` handles these column classes. The behavior of `lm` will be the same for a given column class (numeric, factor, etc.), regardless of why or how the column happens to have that particular class.

Comment: For any person, who can't find the `Auto` data, [here](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Auto.data) it is.

Answer (score 2):

Hxd1011 adressed the more difficult case, when a categorical variable is stored as a number and therefore R understands by default that it is a numerical value - and if this is not the desired behaviour we must use `factor` function.

Your example with predictor `ShelveLoc` in dataset `Carseats` is easier because it's a text (character) variable, and therefore it can only be a categorical variable.

```
> head(Carseats$ShelveLoc)
[1] Bad    Good   Medium Medium Bad    Bad   
Levels: Bad Good Medium
```

Answer (score 2):

R decides that thing from the features type. You can check that by using the str(dataset).If the feature is factor type then it will create dummies for that feature.